# NodeJS/MongoDB Unique Value Check

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm developing an ephemeral encrypted chatroom on the MEAN stack and am wondering how best to structure this bit of code...

What I'm trying to achieve:

- POST request is received to create a chatroom.
- Random 8 character string is generated which will become the roomid (separate from the mongo _id)
- Need to make sure the string doesn't already exist in the database. If it does, I need to run generator and save again.

I have this code which obviously won't work because the call to the database is asynchronous and will cause the thread to crash.

```
var chatroom = new Chatroom();
        var roomid = random.generate(8).toUpperCase();
        var unique = false;

        while (!unique) {
            Chatroom.count({roomid: roomid}, function (error, data) {
                if (data < 1) {
                    chatroom.roomid = roomid;
                    chatroom.roomtitle = request.body.roomtitle;
                    chatroom.passphrase = request.body.passphrase;
                    unique = true;
                }
            });
        }

        chatroom.save(function (error) {
            if (error) {
                response.json(apiResponse('fail', error));
            }
            else {
                response.json(apiResponse('success', chatroom));
            }
        });
```

Any suggestions on how to better structure this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little rusty with MongoDB, but perhaps this might help:

```
var chatroom = new Chatroom();

function generate() {    
    var roomid = random.generate(8).toUpperCase();
    Chatroom.find({roomid: roomid}, function (error, data) {
        if (data.length) {
            chatroom.roomid = roomid;
            chatroom.roomtitle = request.body.roomtitle;
            chatroom.passphrase = request.body.passphrase;
            save();
        }
        else {
            generate();
        }
    });
}

function save () {  
    chatroom.save(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            response.json(apiResponse('fail', error));
        }
        else {
            response.json(apiResponse('success', chatroom));
        }
    });
}
```

I usually find recursion a nicer way of implementing these solutions that iteration - more intuitive at least.

Comment: Agreed. I think there is a better way, but I don't remember it either.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. Should have thought of the recursive option sooner :( All working now. Cheers.

Comment: I would use increment rather looking for the random number.

Comment: @webduvet if you've got a better solution feel free to post it dude, as I say rusty on mongodb :)